# What does a JIT compiler do?

Tags: compiler-construction, jit

I was just watching the Google IO videos and they talked about the JIT compiler that they included in the android. They showed a demo of performance improvements thanks to the JIT compiler. I wondered what does exactly a JIT compiler do and wanted to hear from different people.

So, what is the duty of a JIT compiler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a just-in-time (JIT) compiler do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95635/what-does-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler-do)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Java code is normally distributed as bytecode, which is **machine-independent pseudocode**. (The same idea was previously used in *UCSD-p system* developed in the 70'ies.) The advantage of this is that the same application can be run in different processors and operating systems. In addition, the bytecode is often smaller than compiled application.

The disadvantage is that interpreting the code is **slow** compared to running compiled code.
To solve this problem, **JIT compiler** was developed. JIT compiler compiles the code into machine code just before the code is executed. This speeds up the execution compared to interpreter, but additional time is spent for compiling every time the program is run.
In addition, since JIT compiler must compile fast, it can not use complex optimization techniques that are used in static compilers.

Another approach is **HotSpot** compiling. It initially runs as interpreter, but then detects which routines are used most often and compiles only those. The advantage is that there is no initial delay due to the compiling. In addition, HotSpot compiler may do profiling during the execution and then issue stronger optimization for the most important routines. It may even gather information so that when you run the same application again and again, it will run faster and faster. More information about HotSpot compiling can be found from [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp12214/) (tnx Pangea for the link).

Of course, instead of using JIT compiler, you could just use a static compiler to compile the bytecode for your machine. This allows full optimization and then you do not need to compile again every time you run the application. However, in phones and web pages, you often just execute the code (or applet) once, so JIT compiler may be a better choice.

**Update**

Python bytecode files have extension .py. When you execute the bytecode file, Python JIT compiler produces compiled file .pyc. Next time you run the same program, if the .py file has not changed, there is no need to compile it again but instead Python runs the previously compiled .pyc file. This speeds up the start of the program.

Comment: @PauliL: if JIT transforms byte code to machine understandable format, so how is byte code platform independent?

Comment: @ShardaPrasadJaiswal: Bytecode is platform independent. JOT compiler compiles it into the native code of your computer when you run the program.

Answer (score 13):

JIT is short for "just in time". A JIT compiler compiles code, which is often in an intermediate language like Java bytecode or Microsoft IL, into native, executable code, and it does this at the moment that the code is called. So until the code is called, it exists only in portable, non-machine specific bytecode or IL, and then when it is called, native code is generated (which is then re-used on subsequent calls).

Answer (score 7):

It's a just-in-time compiler, half-way between an interpreter and a compiler (i.e. it compiles, but only just before the code is executed).

This enables optimisations to the compilation using dynamic information only known at runtime (as compilers usually run statically, and so only have access to compile-time information). They're a lot harder to write, but can give great performance improvements.

For more information, as always, [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation):

> In computing, just-in-time compilation (JIT), also known as dynamic translation, is a technique for improving the runtime performance of a computer program. Traditionally, computer programs had two modes of runtime operation, either interpreted or static (ahead-of-time) compilation. Interpreted code was translated from a high-level language to a machine code continuously during every execution, whereas static compilation translated code into machine code before execution, and only required this translation once.
>
> JIT compilers represented a hybrid approach, with translation occurring continuously, as with interpreters, but with caching of translated code to minimize performance degradation. It also offers other advantages over statically compiled code at development time, such as handling of late-bound data types and the ability to enforce security guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

JIT = Just in Time.  It's a process whereby a program that would otherwise be interpreted (e.g. Java bytecodes or Javascript code) is converted to native machine code on the fly as it runs to improve performance.

Some of the benefits are the JIT compiler can see the hotspots and apply more aggressive optimisations, it can also take advantage of any extensions the current processor has like SSE2.

This question may have more info:
[How a JIT compiler helps performance of applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828623/how-a-jit-compiler-helps-performance-of-applications)

Answer (score 2):

> So, What is the duty of a JIT
>   compiler?

As others mentioned it's short for "Just In Time", which in this sense means "Just in time for execution".

When you compile programs to machine code, they are often targeted to a certain platform.

Therefore **JIT** was "Invented", you want to compile the last bits and pieces of your code for the executing platform, so see this as an "before exection"-compiler/optimizer.

*JIT* makes our lives easier and makes (hopefully) our applications run faster.

There are of course other [purposes of JIT-compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), the above is just one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty nice explanation:

"In practice, methods are not compiled the first time they are called. For each method, the JVM maintains a call count, which is incremented every time the method is called. **The JVM interprets a method until its call count exceeds a JIT compilation threshold**. Therefore, often-used methods are compiled soon after the JVM has started, and less-used methods are compiled much later, or not at all. The JIT compilation threshold helps the JVM start quickly and still have improved performance. The threshold has been carefully selected to obtain an optimal balance between startup times and long term performance.

After a method is compiled, its call count is reset to zero and subsequent calls to the method continue to increment its count. When the call count of a method reaches a JIT recompilation threshold, the JIT compiler compiles it a second time, applying a larger selection of optimizations than on the previous compilation. This process is repeated until the maximum optimization level is reached. **The busiest methods of a Java program are always optimized most aggressively, maximizing the performance benefits of using the JIT compiler.** The JIT compiler can also measure operational data at run time, and use that data to improve the quality of further recompilations.

The JIT compiler can be disabled, in which case the entire Java program will be interpreted. Disabling the JIT compiler is not recommended except to diagnose or work around JIT compilation problems."

Source: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.71.doc/diag/understanding/jit_overview.html

Answer (score 1):

A JIT compiler is usually the last part of a VM's pipeline and generates machine code from the VM's intermediary language.

It improves speed by optimizing the generated code for the environment it runs on (CPU specific instructions, cache size,...).

Traditional compilers also optimize the generated machine code but they have to do it without being aware of the specific resources that will be available at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler is a component of the Java™ Runtime Environment that improves the performance of Java applications at run time.

Refer to the IBM documentation [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.aix.70.doc/diag/understanding/jit_overview.html).

The interpreter basically does this:

1. Read the next bytecode to be executed
2. Look at what the bytecode is and find the native machine instruction(s) that correspond to it
3. Execute the native machine instruction(s)
4. Go to step 1

That is simple, it works well, and it will run your Java program. But it's also inefficient, because looking up the native instruction(s) for every single bytecode to be executed costs processing time. So the JVM contains a second mechanism, the Just-In-Time compiler, which basically does this:

1. Read all the bytecodes for the method that needs to be executed
2. Convert all those bytecodes to native machine instructions
3. Execute the generated native machine instructions

After it has converted the bytecodes for a method to native machine instructions, the JVM remembers that native code, so that the next time the method has to be run, it can simply run the native instructions - it doesn't need to convert the bytecodes every time the method is run. This makes the program run much faster.

Also, the JIT performs lots of optimizations to generate native code that runs as fast as possible.

Comment: This question had a number of decent answers already; not sure why it needed a copy-and-paste of existing content.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I landed on this question and found no where clear mentioning that JIT is kind of alternative to interpreter. Only after doing some more research I got a clear insight of it.I only posted so that it could help others. Specially the IBM documentation is very helpful.

Comment: Two of the top three answers were quite clear about the comparison to interpreters.

Comment: @AniketThakur seconded.^

Answer (score 0):

Doubt 
Sir if javac is a Java compiler its role is to convert source code to byte code means .Class  and then .class (byte code)  is interpreted by Java interpretor (Java)  means by JVM and JIT is the part of JVM then what is its actual work